Model-based reinforcement learning code training is too slow, only 3 epochs (3000 steps) in 12 hours
I am a researcher of model-based reinforcement learning. I added the Normalizing flow model to my code to obtain better simulation samples through the flow. I integrated and debugged the two parts for a long time. Now the code can run but the training speed is extremely fast. Slow. I ran three epochs from 10 o'clock last night to 10 o'clock this morning, which is 3000 steps. This is abnormal.  What may be the cause?
This is my train function:
def train(args, env_sampler, predict_env, agent, env_pool, model_pool, couple_flow, rewarder, model_agent, rollout_schedule):
    total_step = 0
    rollout_length =1
    rollout_depth =2
    exploration_before_start(args, env_sampler, env_pool, agent)

    for epoch_step in range(args.num_epoch):
        start_step = total_step
        train_policy_steps = 0
        for i in count():
            cur_step = total_step - start_step

            if cur_step >= args.epoch_length and len(env_pool) > args.min_pool_size:  # epoch_length is 1000
                break

            if args.use_algo == 'discriminator':
                if i == 0:
                    train_predict_model(args, env_pool, predict_env)
                    print("completed model!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                #function2
                train_couple_flow(args, env_pool, predict_env, agent, rollout_depth, rewarder, total_step)
                if cur_step > 0 and cur_step % args.model_train_freq == 0 and args.real_ratio < 1.0:
                    print("start train model")
                    train_predict_model(args, env_pool, predict_env)
                    print("end train model")
                    new_rollout_length = set_rollout_length(epoch_step, rollout_schedule)
                    if rollout_length != new_rollout_length:
                        rollout_length = new_rollout_length
                        model_pool = resize_model_pool(args, rollout_length, model_pool)
                    print("start rollouting")

                    MPC_rollout_model(args, predict_env, agent, model_pool, env_pool, rollout_length, rewarder, total_step)
                    # rollout_model(args, predict_env, agent, model_pool, env_pool, rollout_length)
                    print("end rollouting")
            elif args.use_algo == 'flowrl':
                if i == 0:
                    train_predict_model(args, env_pool, predict_env)
                #function1
                train_predict_model_by_couple_flow(args, env_pool, predict_env, agent, rollout_depth, rewarder, model_agent, cur_step, total_step)
                if cur_step > 0 and cur_step % args.model_train_freq == 0 and args.real_ratio < 1.0:
                    #  if cur_step > 0 and cur_step % 500 == 0 and args.real_ratio < 1.0:

                    new_rollout_length = set_rollout_length(epoch_step, rollout_schedule)
                    if rollout_length != new_rollout_length:
                        rollout_length = new_rollout_length
                        model_pool = resize_model_pool(args, rollout_length, model_pool)

                    rollout_model(args, predict_env, agent, model_pool, env_pool, rollout_length)
            elif args.use_algo == 'mbpo':
                if cur_step > 0 and cur_step % args.model_train_freq == 0 and args.real_ratio < 1.0:
                    train_predict_model(args, env_pool, predict_env)

                    new_rollout_length = set_rollout_length(epoch_step, rollout_schedule)
                    if rollout_length != new_rollout_length:
                        rollout_length = new_rollout_length
                        model_pool = resize_model_pool(args, rollout_length, model_pool)

                    rollout_model(args, predict_env, agent, model_pool, env_pool, rollout_length)


            cur_state, action, next_state, reward, done, info = env_sampler.sample(agent)
            env_pool.push(cur_state, action, reward, next_state, done)

            if len(env_pool) > args.min_pool_size:
                train_policy_steps += train_policy_repeats(args, total_step, train_policy_steps, cur_step, env_pool, model_pool, agent)

            total_step += 1

            if total_step % args.epoch_length == 0:
                '''
                avg_reward_len = min(len(env_sampler.path_rewards), 5)
                avg_reward = sum(env_sampler.path_rewards[-avg_reward_len:]) / avg_reward_len
                logging.info("Step Reward: " + str(total_step) + " " + str(env_sampler.path_rewards[-1]) + " " + str(avg_reward))
                print(total_step, env_sampler.path_rewards[-1], avg_reward)
                '''
                env_sampler.current_state = None
                sum_reward = 0
                done = False
                test_step = 0

                while (not done) and (test_step != args.max_path_length):
                    cur_state, action, next_state, reward, done, info = env_sampler.sample(agent, eval_t=True)
                    sum_reward += reward
                    test_step += 1
                # logger.record_tabular("total_step", total_step)
                # logger.record_tabular("sum_reward", sum_reward)
                # logger.dump_tabular()

                folder_path = f"./results/{args.env_name}"
                if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
                    os.makedirs(folder_path)

                if args.use_algo == 'discriminator':
                    file_name = f"{folder_path}/{args.env_name}_discriminator_{now02}.txt"
                elif args.use_algo == 'flowrl':
                    file_name = f"{folder_path}/{args.env_name}_flowRL_{now02}.txt"
                elif args.use_algo == 'mbpo':
                    file_name = f"{folder_path}/{args.env_name}_mbpo_{now02}.txt"

                with open(file_name, "a") as file:
                    file.write(f"{total_step}\t{sum_reward}\n")

                logging.info("Step Reward: " + str(total_step) + " " + str(sum_reward))
                print(total_step, sum_reward)
                torch.cuda.empty_cache()

I tried increasing the batch_size of the stream from 100 to 256 to 500, reducing file IO, and changing to a better graphics card(Tesla-v100-SXM2-32GB). , but seems to have little effect.

have you made sure that the gpu is being utilized? try to see what the gpu utilization looks like using nvidia-smi?

Yes, I'm sure it's using the gpu. A few days ago, I tried to set the frequency of training the flow model to update once every epoch, and found that the speed improved a lot. Other than these, I still haven't found any reason.
